# Spring Boot FilterChain increase api response time and is a hot spot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jprofiler

I have a question about the filterchain in spring boot, since it's identified as a hot spot in Jprofiler for increasing the response time. Is this normal or we didn't use the filterchain in a right way? Any optimization we can do to it to reduce the response time?

[image: jprofiler screenshot-1]

[image: jprofiler screenshot-2]

Comment: `ProjectTaskResource.getProjectTasksByProject...` is a hot spot not the `FilterChain`.

Comment: @Strelok please check my comment below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the call graph, the node background color indicates which of the displayed methods have the most self-time. This does not mean that they are "hot spots" on a global level.

Your second screen shot shows the "hot spots" view in JProfiler which is the right place to look for hot spots.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The way i'm using JProfiler to find the hot spot is I use the second screen to see the hot spot, e.g. ProjectTaskResource.getProjectTasksByProject... then i expand that to see which method has most self-time, which is like the hot spot of the hot spot. So ProjectTaskResource.getProjectTasksByProject... is the method to be called for /minProjectTasksByProject endpoint, and it's going through XAuthTokenFilter first, which is calling FilterChain.doFilter, that's how i perceive it as a hot spot. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks. @Strelok Please see my comment here.

Comment: The backtraces in the hot spots view show how the hot spot is called but the nodes in the backtraces are not hot spots themselves - the can just delegate calls. The numbers on the backtrace nodes all refer to the top-level hot spot.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! Am i able to diagnose which part in the method is causing the hot spot? Is the call graph used for that that the self-time indicates the potential cause?

Comment: The hot spot is a hot spot because it consumes a lot of time itself, either directly in the method or in outgoing calls that are not profiled. The latter happens if you look a class that is in a "compact" filter (i.e. profiled itself, but without outgoing calls).